# how to error check user input when using .isalpha

Tags: python, loops, error-handling

so I am trying to design a program which simulates a garden, one of the functions I have coded works from the user inputting a plant name such as fern or apple tree.

```
def add_plant(plant_list, total_food,):
    new_plant = get_valid_name("")
    if new_plant in plant_list:
        print("invalid choice")
    elif len(new_plant) > total_food:
            print(f"{new_plant} would cost {len(new_plant)} food. with only {total_food}, you can't afford it")
    else:
        plant_list.append(new_plant.title)
        used_food = len(new_plant)
        total_food -= used_food
    return total_food
```

my code is as below, the reason I wrote it like this is I want to make sure the program loops back if either nothing is entered into the input or the user enters a number. But I find when trying to test it by  adding plants such as sweet potato or apple tree I am greeted with the invalid choice print.

I was wondering how I could code this error check so that it checks for blank spaces and numbers while also letting the user input names of plants which are more than one word long.

```
def get_valid_name(plant,):
    while True:
        plant = input("Enter plant name:").title()
        if plant.isalpha():
            return true
        else:
            print("Invalid plant name")
```

Comment: Your function just returns `true`, not the plant name that was entered.

Answer (score 0):

Remove spaces using `string.replace()` and test `isdigit()` or `isalpha()` for each character.

Pythons `any()` function will test if any condition is met while iterating, so test for if a char is neither a digit or an alpha character. It also short circuits, so it is faster than list comprehension.

```
def get_valid_name(plant):
    is_valid = False
    while not is_valid:
        plant = input("Enter plant name:").title()
        without_spaces = plant.replace(' ', '')
        is_valid = not(any(!(c.isdigit() or c.isalpha()) for c in without_spaces))
    return plant
```

Comment: It's better to use the `any()` or `all()` function instead of a list comprehension.

Comment: Can you clarify? Also this is set logic, not a list comprehension.

Comment: Same difference. `if any(!(c.isdigit() or c.isalpha()) for c in plant.replace(' ', '')):`

Comment: This is correct and faster. Will update the answer.

Comment: `any()` stops as soon as the condition is matched, your code checks every character.

Comment: Never heard of or used the `any()` function before. Once I saw the syntax, I definitely agreed. Set comprehension is fast, but short circuiting is faster. Although probably excessive optimization for the problem.

Comment: `any()` and `all()` are some of the first [built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
def get_valid_name():
    while (plant := input().strip()).isdigit() or not plant: pass
    return plant.title()
```

Comment: this is good, although I need a statement to be printed if the user gets the input wrong such as if they type 1 or leave it blank. instead of just needing more entries, it prints a statement like "invalid choice" then continues the loop

Comment: just change the `pass` statement to `print('invalid choice')`